# Как в несколько потоков прочитать ОГРОМНЫЙ (скажем ~25 ГБ) xml файл?

Tags: java, xml, многопоточность, парсер

структура xml довольно простая...

Но размер файла довольно большой....

Хочется читать файл в несколько параллельных потоков...

Как в несколько потоков прочитать ОГРОМНЫЙ  xml файл?

какой парсер вы бы посоветовали ?

**UPD:**

Файл имеет не сложную структуру... сильной вложенности нет...

Кусочек файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageBOMs Date="2016-01-01" Time="00:00:00" System_ID="EGP" Client="1000" DateAktualn="2016-09-13" Version="BOM_007">
    <BOM ST_LNR="00677090" ST_LAL="01" MA_TNR_EXT="СТУ1003094А" WERKS="" ST_LAN="1" BM_ENG="1.000" BM_EIN="ШТ" LA_BOR="GKB" ST_LST="10" ZT_EXT="">
        <pos POS_NR="9000" ID_NRK="0202-09060-00006" PO_STP="L" SO_RTF="07" MENGE="0.060" MEINS="КГ" RE_KRS="false" SAN_KO="false" SAN_FE="true" SANKA="true" RV_REL="false" ZM_CMP="false" Z_WEIGHT_DETAIL="0.012" UNIT="KG" ZSIZE_DIMENSIONS="24" ZWEIGHT_BLANK="0.033" UNIT_B="KG" ALPRF="00" EWAHR="0" BEIKZ="" SCHGT="false" LGORT="" ITSOB="" IDENT="00000001"/>
    </BOM>
    <BOM ST_LNR="00677091" ST_LAL="01" MA_TNR_EXT="КПК0114624" WERKS="" ST_LAN="1" BM_ENG="1.000" BM_EIN="ШТ" LA_BOR="GKB" ST_LST="10" ZT_EXT="">
        <pos POS_NR="9000" ID_NRK="0201-09080-00044" PO_STP="L" SO_RTF="07" MENGE="24.000" MEINS="КГ" RE_KRS="false" SAN_KO="false" SAN_FE="true" SANKA="true" RV_REL="false" ZM_CMP="false" Z_WEIGHT_DETAIL="9.850" UNIT="KG" ZSIZE_DIMENSIONS="163" ZWEIGHT_BLANK="19.400" UNIT_B="KG" ALPRF="00" EWAHR="0" BEIKZ="" SCHGT="false" LGORT="" ITSOB="" IDENT="00000001"/>
        <pos POS_NR="9000" ID_NRK="0201-09080-00044" PO_STP="L" SO_RTF="07" MENGE="24.000" MEINS="шт" RE_KRS="false" SAN_KO="false" SAN_FE="true" SANKA="true" RV_REL="false" ZM_CMP="false" Z_WEIGHT_DETAIL="9.850" UNIT="KG" ZSIZE_DIMENSIONS="163" ZWEIGHT_BLANK="19.400" UNIT_B="KG" ALPRF="00" EWAHR="0" BEIKZ="" SCHGT="false" LGORT="" ITSOB="" IDENT="00000001"/>
        <pos POS_NR="9000" ID_NRK="0201-09080-00044" PO_STP="L" SO_RTF="07" MENGE="24.000" MEINS="КГ" RE_KRS="false" SAN_KO="false" SAN_FE="true" SANKA="true" RV_REL="false" ZM_CMP="false" Z_WEIGHT_DETAIL="9.850" UNIT="KG" ZSIZE_DIMENSIONS="163" ZWEIGHT_BLANK="19.400" UNIT_B="KG" ALPRF="00" EWAHR="0" BEIKZ="" SCHGT="false" LGORT="" ITSOB="" IDENT="00000001"/>
        <pos POS_NR="9000" ID_NRK="0201-09080-00044" PO_STP="L" SO_RTF="07" MENGE="24.000" MEINS="КГ" RE_KRS="false" SAN_KO="false" SAN_FE="true" SANKA="true" RV_REL="false" ZM_CMP="false" Z_WEIGHT_DETAIL="9.850" UNIT="KG" ZSIZE_DIMENSIONS="163" ZWEIGHT_BLANK="19.400" UNIT_B="KG" ALPRF="00" EWAHR="0" BEIKZ="" SCHGT="false" LGORT="" ITSOB="" IDENT="00000001"/>
        <pos POS_NR="9000" ID_NRK="0201-09080-00044" PO_STP="L" SO_RTF="07" MENGE="24.000" MEINS="л" RE_KRS="false" SAN_KO="false" SAN_FE="true" SANKA="true" RV_REL="false" ZM_CMP="false" Z_WEIGHT_DETAIL="9.850" UNIT="KG" ZSIZE_DIMENSIONS="163" ZWEIGHT_BLANK="19.400" UNIT_B="KG" ALPRF="00" EWAHR="0" BEIKZ="" SCHGT="false" LGORT="" ITSOB="" IDENT="00000001"/>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </BOM>    
    ...
    ...
    ...
</PackageBOMs>
```

К сожалению, этот xml формируется не в нашей компании (у клиентов)...

Доступа к базам данных(4 разных типа БД) на стороне  клиента у нас нет, и быть не может, по соображениям политики безопасности в области информации и чего-то там(одним словом - гос.контора )...

У заказчика нет специалистов и желания переписывать свой софт, который собирает данные из таблиц разных БД и формирует этот xml.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону SAX-парсеров. Но я что-то не представляю себе, как можно потоковый формат наподобие XML эффективно читать в нескольких потоках.

Comment: @VladD,спасибо. Я уже реализовал c использованием SAX  (юзеров устраивает)... Но мне  не очень нравится скорость...  хочется поиграться с оптимизацией скорости загрузки файла...

Comment: разве XMLReader медленно читает ?

Comment: у меня была проблема с чтением большого файла (примерно 6 Гб) и мне помогло только StringTokenizer. в однопоточном режиме занимает пару секунд судя по логам.

Comment: @Senior Automator. Спасибо. XMLReader читает довольно быстро...  но мне кажется что если получится реализовать работу в несколько потоков будет намного быстрее.... 25ГБ файл хоть и большой, но это не максимально возможный размер в моем случае... возможно понадобится обработка файлов и  большего объема...
Я не уверен, что использование StringTokenizer для xml даст прирост в скорости.

Comment: @Senior Automator, бенчмарки в студию, ибо был опыт при 1кк итерациях, не слишком и быстрое чтение. П.С. Тсу в помощь jaxb

Comment: В каком месте bottleneck? Если в чтении с диска - то распараллелить не получится. А если в обработке считанного - то можно.

Comment: Это единоразовая задача? Или такие файлы откуда-то приходят часто? Так-то можно попробовать оптимизировать формат, но это вопрос к генерирующей стороне.

Comment: А что вы собираетесь после чтения файла с ним следать?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov... Конечно же  не в памяти хранить )) 
После парсинга - записываю в БД.
С записью в БД проблем нет...  Явное узкое место - скорость чтения XML

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев а вы замеряли время? Обычно как раз БД узкое место в подобных операциях.

Comment: С учётом всего сказанного, остаётся только применить SSD. Или, как вариант, использовать для хранения таких больших файлов логический диск, отформатированный с кластерами большого размера: 32-64 кб, в завимости от вашей ОС и файловой системы. Чем больше размер кластера, тем быстрее чтение-запись больших файлов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Файлы формата XML, как и любых других LL(n)-подобных грамматик, невозможно читать в несколько потоков. Максимум что вы можете сделать - это сразу после получения данных передавать их в другой поток на обработку, чтобы 1 поток всегда был занят парсингом.

К примеру, если на разбор файла уходит половина времени, и еще половина - на запись в БД, то вынесение работы с БД в другой поток ускорит процесс в два раза.

Здесь вам может пригодиться класс [`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) и паттерн "производитель-потребитель" (Producer-Consumer)

Comment: Не совсем так. Это верно для произвольного XML файла, но неверно может быть для конкретного XML файла. Например если там просто записи <link x="somelink" /> ... однотипные и без вложенности, то читать в несколько потоков будет не проблема. И как раз я думаю что этот файл именно такой.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Ну, хм. Точно так же задача обращения конкретного криптографического хеша может быть легко решаема, но в своей общности...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, спасибо за ответ.
Файл простой. Записи однотипные...
Я добавил пример файла в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что многопоточность не решит проблему...

Вы же читаете файл с одного ЖД=> запустив N потоков, вы упретесь в производительность ЖД.

Как вариант, можно читать непрерывно одним потоком в память, а обрабатывать данные в несколько потоков.

Вроде, паттерн зовет производитель/потребитель.

А почему XML файл может достигать таких размеров? Может быть возможно отказаться от XML, а разместить данные по сущностям в БД?

На мой взгляд, такой размер файла-это не нормально...

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я добавил в вопрос инфу о том, почему файл получается таких размеров (25ГБ это еще не предел..)..
Я полностью согласен с вами, что файлы таких размеров - не нормально.
 Приходится выкручиваться и работать с тем, что есть.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, файл такой структуры легко "парсится в параллель".

Определяете его размер и делите на число потоков-обработчиков. Таким образом каждый поток знает позицию в файле с которой ему надо начать обработку и где ее заканчивать.

Все потоки (кроме первого) позиционируются в нужную точку файла и далее читают файл построчно. После того, как прочитана строка с `</BOM>` (т.е. закрывающий тег для части файла, обрабатываемой *предыдущим* потоком) начинается построчная обработка своей части.

Она завершется, когда поток прочел строку с `</BOM>` в позиции *после* конца своей части.

Понятно, что алгоритм поиска начала обработки для первого и конца обработки для последнего потоков некоторым (надеюсь, очевидным) образом отличны от вышеописанных.

Как именно "подсунуть" в библиотеку парсинга на Java самостоятельно выделяемые фрагменты, извините, не знаю. Лично я (наверное) распарсил бы  их сам, поскольку структура тривиальна.

Даст ли такая потоковая обработка прирост производительности?

Не очевидно
(поскольку чтение с одного и того же диска),
но вполне возможно
(imho за счет распараллеливания запросов на обновление базы данных (однако, это уже сильно зависит от конкретной базы)).

Answer (score -2):

Некоторой альтернативой SAX-парсеру может стать pull-парсер: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.4/scala/xml/pull/XMLEventReader.html
(он из Scala, но из Джавы тоже получится использовать)

Впрочем, вряд ли он сам по себе даст действительно большой выигрыш в скорости.

Вообще, возможна следующая идея - читать этот файл не последовательно, а из нескольких позиций одновременно (скажем, первый гигабайт читается в первом потоке, второй - во втором и так далее). Тебе в этом может помочь https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html (главное, не начни читать посреди xml-тега).

Это непроверенная идея, никогда её не реализовывал. Но она может помочь, т.к. обычно самым большим bottleneck-ом является чтение с диска.

Comment: Ну, начали вы читать с тега на глубине вложенности 25. Ваши действия? Как вы вообще определите, к чему относятся ваши теги?

Comment: Не зная структуры XML-файла - никак. Но в некоторых случаях (например, в root-теге множество небольших несвязанных тегов) имеет смысл "перескакивать" до ближайшего закрывающего такого тега и начинать читать следующий.

Comment: @VladD, ну реализовать можно, если читать начали не с открывающего тега, то помечаем, что объект не полный. Каждый поток читает в свою коллекцию, т.к. позиции с которых начинается чтение нам известны, можем пронумеровать эти коллекции (какие группы объектов). После прочтения файла пройтись по коллекциям найти незавершенные объекты, склеить.

Comment: Но конечно совет используй FileChannel - это в духе "используй язык программирования, Люк!"

Comment: @hardsky: Окей, дочитали до закрывающего тега, а за ним ещё один закрывающий тег. Наши действия? Ваш алгоритм очевиден в случае, если XML выглядит как `<root><element id="1"/><element id="2"/><element id="3"/></root>`. А если там везде вложенные хитрые структуры?

Comment: Не любого закрывающего тега; закрывающего тега, который является непосредственным child root-а, и начинать читать следующий. Вложенную структуру с середины читать смысла особого нет, это понятно.

Я просто подал идею. Уверен, автор вопроса сможет её как-то использовать - в настолько больших файлах, кажется, могут быть такие "последовательные" участки, которые можно читать именно так.

Comment: @VladD, создаю новую "незавершенную" ноду и добавляю туда прочитанный dom. Каждый поток создает свой dom, потом их мержим. Тонкость, конечно в "мержим", я не на 100% уверен в работоспособности.

Comment: @Nartallax: А откуда вы узнаете, что тег является непосредственным потомком рута? Для этого, боюсь, нужно будет прочитать до конца потока.

Comment: @hardsky: Окей, но тогда у нас в памяти 25 ГБ непонятно чего. Мы вылетим по out of memory, боюсь. У меня есть подозрение, что обрабатывать данные необходимо немедленно, при поступлении.

Answer (score -2):

Есть класс RandomAccessFile.
Может читать файл с определённого байта.

```
//r- read, файл открыт только для чтения
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("input.txt", "r"); 
// «курсор» стоит на 0-м символе.
String text1 = raf.readLine();

//перемещаем «курсор» на 100-й символ.
raf.seek(100);
String text2 = raf.readLine();

//перемещаем «курсор» на 0-й символ.
raf.seek(0);
String text3 = raf.readLine();

//закрываем файл
raf.close();
```

Comment: И как это поможет?

Comment: Ну человек хочет читать файл в несколько потоков. Как он данные потом будет склеивать или работать с кусками раздельно - я не знаю, но я подсказал с помощью какого класса можно прочитать кусок файла. Можно разбить на потоки - каждый начнёт со своего байта. И я согласен с написанным тут, что всё упрётся в производительность диска.